# Cut off top and/or bottom pf SVG element

Tags: html, svg

I have an svg element in my html body:

```
<svg height="1000px">...</svg>
```

And inside i have a group which contains other elements. The thing is that the total height of my group is 400px and it is located in the middle of the svg, which leaves me with 600px (300px on top and 300x on bottom) of empty white space.

Is there a way to somehow remove that empty space which occupies my page without any need?

Comment: Just set the height to 400px?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the structure of the SVG you are probably looking for the `viewbox` attribute.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/viewBox

> The viewBox attribute allows you to specify that a given set of
>   graphics stretch to fit a particular container element.

Here's an example:

```css
body {
  background: #c3c3c3;
}

svg {
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}
```

```html
<svg height="200px" width="200px" fill="#fff" viewbox="0 0 50 50">
  <g>
    <rect fill="blue" height="50px" width="50px">
  </g>
</svg>
  
<svg height="200px" width="200px" fill="#fff">
  <g>
    <rect fill="blue" height="50px" width="50px">
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: What also helped is the `preserveAspectRatio="none"` which I had to put in svg element to make sure the area I want to remain is cropped, and not scaled.

Answer (score 1):

[`viewBox`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/viewBox).

Using `viewBox="x y wx wy"` you can define the upper left corner of the rendering area (x/y), as well as the width and height (wx/wy).

Perhaps an example demonstrates this best:

```html
<svg width="200"
     height="200"
     viewBox="800 900 200 200"
     style="border: solid 1px #333;">

    <rect x="800" y="900" width="100" height="100" fill="#090" />
</svg>
```